# Rails divide collection into equal parts, sort each part and join together

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to extract my `Product.where(in_stock: 0)` and `Product.where.not(in_stock: 0)`. Then I want to sort each part of collection by `price ASC` and join them up together with a view to display sorted items in stock first and then sorted item out of stock.

There should be working `.merge` applied to AR relation but it's not working on Rails 5.2.X

Also, Rails 5 is pretty good with finding by sorted array of ids, but it returns an `Array` instead of AR relation.

Is there any way of writing clean and maintainable piece of working code? Popular `Postgres` workarounds fail with collections containing > 100 instances.

Any thoughts on how to implement it with pure SQL?

Answer (score 1):

How about getting it in 1 query instead by using `ORDER`.

```
ORDER BY case in_stock when 0 then 2 else 1 end, net_price ASC
```

This will push all the `in_stock: 0` records to the bottom.

To query with AR

```
Product.all.order(Arel.sql("ORDER BY case in_stock when 0 then 2 else 1 end, net_price ASC"))
```

I'm using `Arel.sql` since there's a deprecation warning:

```
Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s)
```

[Reference to deprecation](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32995)